# c free of two dimensional array gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

Can somebody please explain me way the `free(test[0])` is giving me a `segmentation fault (core dumped)`? I've tried to comment out the free and then the program terminates correctly (except from the lost memory). Also if I comment out `test[0] = "abcd"` and insert the `free(...)` again it terminates correctly too!?

```
char **test = (char**) (malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5));
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  test[i] = (char*) (malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5));
}

test[0] = "abcd";
free(test[0]);
```

Comment: [Dont cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use strcpy instead of == , because here, you just gives test[0] the adresse of a static chain "abcd", that cannot be disallocated like that.

Answer (score 1):

Please see @Fvirtman's answer to fix your crash.

Then to prevent leaks :

test is a two dimentional array so you need to free each one of it's sub-arrays first then free test like this :

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  free(test[i]);
}
free(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your pointer `test[0]` with address of `"abcd"`,which is statically allocated array that resides in read-only area. Add this `printf("%p",test[0]);` before and after `test[0] = "abcd";` for visualisation of what happens.